# Permanently changing a pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to know if there's actually a way to do this easily.  This is just an example of what I want to do...

```
void* ptr;
ptr = new Foo;
((Foo*)ptr)->member1 = some_val;
((Foo*)ptr)->member2 = some_val;
((Foo*)ptr)->member3 = some_val;
((Foo*)ptr)->member4 = some_val;
((Foo*)ptr)->member5 = some_val;
((Foo*)ptr)->member6 = some_val;
```

Because ptr is a void*, is there anyway that I can temporarily change the ptr type, so that I don't have to cast it each time to use it?

I can't just create another pointer of type Foo because ptr is used elsewhere and needs to be of type void.  So I guess, temporarily make it of type Foo to avoid all the messy casting I'm having to do.

** Seems some people are getting confused...  ptr must remain of type void because in the program it's used like this:-

```
void* ptr;
switch (bar)
{
    case 1:
       ptr = new Foo;
       ((Foo*)ptr)->member1 = some_val;
       ((Foo*)ptr)->member2 = some_val;
       ((Foo*)ptr)->member3 = some_val;
       ((Foo*)ptr)->member4 = some_val;
       ((Foo*)ptr)->member5 = some_val;
       ((Foo*)ptr)->member6 = some_val;
    case 2:
       ptr = new Doo;
       ...
    case 3:
       ptr = new Scooby;
       ...
```

So, ptr has to remain of type void. I just wanted to know if there's a temporary way to cast ptr to another type, so avoid the casting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you can't create a temporal pointer:

```
void* ptr;
ptr = new Foo;
{
Foo *pt=(Foo*)ptr;
 pt->member1 = some_val;
 pt->member2 = some_val;
 pt->member3 = some_val;
 pt->member4 = some_val;
 pt->member5 = some_val;
 pt->member6 = some_val;
} 
void *t=ptr; // the original ptr
```

Sometimes I use:

```
Foo &f= *((Foo*)ptr);
 f.member1 = some_val;
 f.member2 = some_val;
 f.member3 = some_val;
 f.member4 = some_val;
 f.member5 = some_val;
 f.member6 = some_val;
```

Comment: Yeah I guess the only way is going to have to be to create a temporary pointer.  Didn't want to do this, but still...

Comment: Do not fear: the compiler should be smart enough to avoid making your memory consumption. 'pt' is perfect candidate for in-register variable.

Comment: @glglgl    of course !! The intentions is JUST to show that ptr has still the void* type :-) , that you can use it as previously

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This answer is obsolete because the original question has been modfied.

You can use:

```
Foo* ptr;

ptr = new Foo;
ptr->member1 = some_val;
ptr->member2 = some_val;
ptr->member3 = some_val;
```

or

```
void* ptrFromElseWhere;
Foo* ptr = static_cast<Foo*>(ptrFromElseWhere);

ptr->member1 = some_val;
ptr->member2 = some_val;
ptr->member3 = some_val;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't really answer the question.  ptr must remain of type void as it assigned different classes, I just want to avoid having to cast the void pointer all the time.

Comment: Multiple classes using a (global?) scope-pointer with their own individual casting ? that sounds like nightmares ahead of the road, imho.

Comment: The thread starter has edited his question after my answer which makes the answer obsolete.